# Angular 2: Singleton Services - Properties not remembered?

Tags: angular, service, singleton

I have a service that is only listed as a provider in my appModule.  It's not in a providers list anywhere else in my application.  Any property I set inside my service is always undefined whenever I navigate away from the component where it is used and come back.  Here is my service...

**LookupsService.ts**

```
import {Injectable, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {Http, Response} from "@angular/http";
import {environment} from "../environments/environment";
import {Lookups} from "./lookups.model";

@Injectable()
export class LookupService {
  private baseUrl: string;
  private lookups: Lookups;

  constructor(private http: Http) {
    this.baseUrl = `${environment.epiApiUrl}/lookups`;
  }

  getAll(): Observable<Lookups> {
    // we should only hit the database to get all the lookups once
    if (this.lookups) { // <-- this.lookups is ALWAYS undefined
      return Observable.of(this.lookups);
    }
    else {
      return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}`)
        .map(this.extractData);
    }
  }

  extractData(response: Response) {
    let responseBody = response.json();
    this.lookups = <Lookups>responseBody.data; // <--why isn't this remembered?
    return this.lookups;
  }
}
```

I use this service in one component only currently...

```
@Component({
  selector: 'addresses',
  templateUrl: './addresses.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./addresses.component.less']
})
export class AddressesComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() user;
  addressTypes: IdValue[] = [];

  constructor(private lookupService: LookupService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.lookupService.getAll()
      .subscribe((lookups) => {
        this.addressTypes = lookups.addressTypes;
      });
  }

}
```

Whenever I change to a different route and come back, the service has to request the lookups from the api each time because this.lookups is always undefined.  The LookupsService constructor is NOT called again, yet lookups property is always undefined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace

```
.map(this.extractData);
```

by

```
.map(response => this.extractData(response));
```

Otherwise, `this` is not bound to the current object anymore.

IMHO, calling `map()` should not have side effects. So I would refactor the code to

```
return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}`)
    .map(response => response.json().data)
    .do(lookups => this.lookups = <Lookups>lookups);
```

That makes it clear that you're

- transforming the HTTP response to something else
- add a side effect of storing the lookups in the lookups field

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly it.  I knew it had to be something stupid I was missing.  I was completely losing my this binding.